# Implementing a Linked List in C++, where am I going wrong?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

This is my first time working with linked lists and I was wondering where exactly am I going wrong in my understanding? I put comments before each line to show what I am trying to do based on my current understanding of linked lists. Based on my while loop I feel that I am doing something wrong because I can not get all the values to print out in the list.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    struct node{
      int data;
      node* next;
    };

    int main()
    {
    //creating a head pointer
      node* head = NULL;
    //creating new node 
      node* temp = new node;
    //giving new node data(2)
      temp->data = 2;
    //node does not point to another node
      temp->next = NULL;
    //pointing head to temp(connecting them)
      head = temp;
    //creating a new node
      node*temp1 = new node;
    //giving new node data 3
      temp1->data = 3;
    //new node is not pointing to anything
      temp1->next = NULL;
    //connecting temp node to temp1 node
      temp = temp1;
    //creating a node that will start at head to allow me to print                                 
    //all the values in the list by traversing through it
      node* trav = new node;
    //setting trav equal to head so it starts from the beginning of
    //list
      trav = head;
      while(trav->next != NULL){
       trav = trav->next;
       std::cout<<trav->data;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The best way to debug pointers is to use pen(cil) and paper and draw where everything points at each step.

Comment: It is a must to do what @molbdnilo stated.  When you get an assignment with linked list, it should be done with pencil and paper **first**, drawing boxes and lines.  Unless you're an experienced programmer,. you cannot code your way to a linked list without that step.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand what your saying and I did take that necessary step before trying to code it. I put the comments before each line to try to explain what I was trying to do based on my current understanding so people reading it could know what I was attempting.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you for that, I know it is something that I am gonna need to do and it definitely helped when I went back to see what my code was doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is here:

```
//connecting temp node to temp1 node
  temp = temp1;
```

You probably meant:

```
//connecting temp node to temp1 node
  temp->next = temp1;
```

---

You also have a memory leak here:

```
node* trav = new node;
//setting trav equal to head so it starts from the beginning of
//list
  trav = head;
```

This should just be:

```
//setting trav equal to head so it starts from the beginning of
//list
node* trav = head;
```

Comment: Only other issue is with the while loop itself. Don't check for trav->next being null, check for trav itself being null. The way you have the loop right now, you won't cout your last element because the last element links to null, even though it is itself valid.